# Displaying the categories to which something has been assigned, in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have these tables:

articles:

```
id: | name:     | ... | category:
1   | article 1 | ... | cat1
2   | article 2 | ... | cat2
3   | article 3 | ... | NULL
4   | article 4 | ... | NULL
5   | article 5 | ... | cat1
```

categories:

```
id: | name:         | ... | url:
1   | Some Category | ... | cat1
2   | Kats          | ... | cat2
3   | Dogs          | ... | cat3
4   | Pigs          | ... | cat4
```

`articles.category` is a foreign key for `categories.url`. In the blog page I have a list of all articles (regardless of category, `SELECT * FROM articles`).

Now I want to make category list menu - so I can view articles assigned to chosen category
(already done: `SELECT * FROM articles WHERE category='$some_url'`).

To avoid a situation when none of the articles is assigned to chosen category (in the example above: none of the articles are assigned to Dogs or Pigs) instead of message like: "There is no articles in this category" I would like to display only those categories to which are assigned some articles.

For example above this would be "Some Category" and "kats".

Comment: Well I would suggest you to do this in the PHP code. You have a STRING or NULL in the category column. Simply an if statement could fix this `if($var != NULL) { // do code }`

Comment: Sorry, but it does not help in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible query could be:

```
SELECT * FROM categories WHERE url IN (SELECT DISTINCT category FROM articles);
```

Or:

```
SELECT c.* FROM categories c LEFT JOIN articles a ON (c.url = a.category) WHERE a.category != '' GROUP BY c.url
```

Comment: Thanks :) !.Both of queries works, so which one should be used?